# Why is "UVs" menu not visible?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm following this CG Cookie [tutorial](https://vimeo.com/17885651).

I have a tree mesh, and loaded the image. But there is no "UVs" menu, where I could find the "unwrap" function. There is only `View` and `Image`. After them should be located the `UVs`

[image: no UVs menu]

Comment: You need to be in Edit mode to UV unwrap.

Answer (score 8):

That menu shows up in Edit mode, and only when the mesh is already UV unwrapped.

(Click on the images to get a larger view)
Object mode:
 [image]

Edit mode, not yet unwrapped:
 [image]

Edit mode, unwrapped:
 [image]

To unwrap, make sure you're in Edit mode, then hit <kbd>U</kbd> or click Mesh > UV Unwrap and select a suitable option from the menu that shows up.
 [image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry for the late reply, but I can try it just on this weekend.

Comment: @IterAtor No problem. :)